# Why is the head of my custom skin white?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a skin for MineCraft and when I went to use it the head was all white. Every time I try to make a skin this happens. What do I do I've tried countless skin editors and always end up with a white head.

First I made a skin, then I install it, next I start MineCraft, then I go in my inventory and bam! My head is white.

I've used skin editing tools and installed the skin and every time the head is white.

Comment: Post the skin or we can't tell you why.

Comment: I'm going to postulate that you've left a section of the skin picture white when it should be top-of-head colored instead.

Comment: Make sure you're not wearing an iron helmet.

Comment: You used Microsoft Paint at least once to edit your skin. MSPaint turns everything transparent white and if you save it it will be white in any photo editor.

Answer (score 30):

There are two likely possibilities here.

#### 1. You didn't colour in the head in the head region.

Minecraft skins have particular regions for particular parts of the skin. Wherever you're colouring, it's not where the head is supposed to be.

[image: Colouring regions for Minecraft skins]

*Skin-sized version:* [image: Skin-sized colouring regions reference]

*I didn't make this reference image - only the smaller version. It's one of the most useful references I've found.*

#### 2. You didn't make the Head Accessory transparent

Here's the default Minecraft skin viewed in Photoshop zoomed in:

[image: Default Minecraft skin showing transparency]

The limbs, body and head are fully coloured, as is required.

The head accessory - which is a box that wraps around your character's head, allowing you to give it a helmet or crown (for instance) is *transparent*.

It's very probable that whatever skin you're using, you've left the head accessory regions white. So now you have a white box wrapped around your character's head (not an invisible box) - so your character appears to have a white head.

Comment: While not pertinent to the question, it's worth noting that the head accessory is the *only* part of the player skin which supports transparency.  Any transparency on other parts of the body appears solid black in-game.  (So it isn't possible to make, for example, a headless character.)

Comment: @BenBlank This isn't true! Only the outer head (head accessories) can be made transparent!

Comment: @Timtech That appears to be precisely what he is saying. :P

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Oops I thought he said it *was* possible to make a headless character. My mistake :)

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is that you edited the skin in microsoft paint, which doesn't maintain the transparency of the skin, so the "helmet" area ends up white.

The quick fix is to download a copy of Gimp, or Paint.net

Each of these can properly handle transparency in PNG images, and are legally free.